# Replace contents of string based on multiple named regexp matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to reformat a bunch of SQL queries. As it is, a query like this generates a syntax error:

```
insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, Pete, My Address Line);
```

It actually needs to be

```
 insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, "Pete", "My Address Line");
```

Note the quotes around the arguments for `name` and `address`.

I'm having a hard timing doing this with `gsub`. I've written the following regexp:

```
regexp = /insert into table_name \(id, name, address \) values \(.+?, (?<name>.+?), (?<address>.+?)\);/
```

And now want to add quotes around the contents of the named matches `name` and `address`. How to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility :

```
sql = "insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, Pete, My Address Line);
insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (5, John, My Address Line 2);"

columns_to_replace = %w(name address)

new_sql = sql.gsub(/\((.*?)\) values \((.*?)\)/) do
  columns = Regexp.last_match(1).split(', ')
  values = columns.zip(Regexp.last_match(2).split(', ')).map do |column, value|
    if columns_to_replace.include? column
      format('"%s"', value)
    else
      value
    end
  end
  format('(%s) values (%s)', columns.join(', '), values.join(', '))
end

puts new_sql
# insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, "Pete", "My Address Line");
# insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (5, "John", "My Address Line 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following *regex* to capture the query string and add `" "` around name and address by replacing the string with captured group:

```
input        >>  insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, Pete, My Address Line);
regex search >>  (insert\sinto\stable_name\s\(id,\sname,\saddress\)\svalues\s\(.+?,\s)(?<name>.+?),\s(?<address>.+?)(\);)
replace with >>  $1"$2", "$3"$4
output       >>  insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, "Pete", "My Address Line");
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/1mo5UI/1)

**ruby** *(possibly)*

```
re = /(insert\sinto\stable_name\s\(id,\sname,\saddress\)\svalues\s\(.+?,\s)(?<name>.+?),\s(?<address>.+?)(\);)/
str = 'insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, Pete, My Address Line);'
subst = '$1"$2", "$3"$4'

result = str.gsub(re, subst)
puts result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    values\s\(\d+,\s+  # match string
    \K                 # discard match so far
    ([^,]+)            # match all characters other than a comma in capture group 1
    ,\s                # match a comma followed by a space
    ([^)]+)            # match all characters other than a right paren in capture group 2  
    /x                 # free-spacing regex definition mode

sql = "insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, Pete, My Address Line);"

puts sql.sub(r, '"\1", "\2"')
```

prints

```
insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, "Pete", "My Address Line");
```

Note that I cannot wrap `values\s\(\d+,\s+` in a positive lookbehind because it is variable length. It is for that reason that I've employed the greatly-underused `\K` directive.

Answer (score -1):

```
wrong_query = "insert into table_name (id, name, address) values (4, Pete, My Address Line);"
right_query = wrong_query.gsub(regexp) do |query|
  name = Regexp.last_match(1)
  address = Regexp.last_match(2)
  [name, address].each do |capture|
    query.sub!(capture, '"' + capture + '"')
  end
  query
end
```

This can probably go horribly wrong when the name or address captures are not unique in the overall string, but for my case, it is sufficient.